# window.outerWidth equals 0 when out of focus tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `window.outerWidth` to get the width of the window which works fine. The problem is however that `window.outerWidth` will be `0` if you load the page in a tab that is not in focus. Is there any workaround for this?

The same behavior is on Chrome and Firefox.

**Solution:** I decided to use `window.innerWidth` instead since it gives the correct width even when the tab is out of focus and gave the same desired results in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the width within the window onfocus event handler.

```
window.onfocus = function() { };
```

Answer (score 0):

Very weird behaviour...

Here's the Chromium bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=719296

Seems this is now only applicable to Chrome-based browsers on macOS.